# What 2nd order homogeneous differential equation does $y_c=c_1\cos x+ c_2 x\cos x$ come from?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\cos x$ and $x \cos x$ are linearly independent on the interval $(-1,1)$ and so they must be a basis for some homogeneous 2nd order linear equation on this interval.

My question then is, how can I find $p(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $y_c=c_1\cos x +c_2x\cos x$ satisfies:

$$y''+p(x)y'+g(x)y=0$$

We have that:

$$y_cg(x)=(c_1\cos x+c_2 x\ cos x)g(x)$$
$$y_c'p(x)=(-c_1\sin x+ c_2 \cos x -c_2 x\sin x)p(x)$$
$$y_c''=-c_1\cos x- 2c_2\sin x -c_2x\cos x$$

So far I've tried different combinations such as $g(x)=1+\sin x$ with $p(x)=\cos x$ and $g(x)=1$ with $p(x)=0$, but I all my attempts thus far have failed. Any help on this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to verify that you must have $\left(\frac{y(x)}{\cos x}\right)''=0$, as the division by the cosine leaves a linear function on the other side.